# Convergence of probability measures converging on generating set

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, product-measure

Let $(X,\mathcal{A})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{B})$ be two measurable spaces and let $(\mathbf{P}_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of probability measures in $(X\times Y, \mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{B})$ that satisfies the following condition:

*There exists a set function $\mathbf{P}\colon \mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{B}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that for every $A\times B \in \mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{B}$ it holds that $\mathbf{P}_n(A\times B)\rightarrow \mathbf{P}(A\times B)$, when $n\rightarrow \infty$.*

The question is, can $\mathbf{P}$ always be extended to a measure $\hat{\mathbf{P}}$ in $(X\times Y, \mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{B})$ or are there counterexamples? Furthermore, is this extension unique if it exists?

Comment: It follows from a standard application of the $\pi-\lambda$-theorem that a probability measure on a product $\sigma$-algebra is uniquely determined by its values on measurable rectangles, so there can be at most one such measure. One could obtain a positive answer from the Caratheodory extension theorem if one could prove that $\mathbf{P}$ is countably additive on the semi-ring of measurable rectangles.